# Why is Integer inferred when the type variable should be ambiguous?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

This tiny Haskell program reads two space-separated numbers from console and prints their sum:

```
main = do
  line <- getLine
  let n1:n2:_ = map read $ words line
  print $ n1 + n2
```

I'd expect the compilation to fail because of ambiguity: `+` restricts the type of `n1` and `n2` to `Num` typeclass and not to a specific type. However GHC 7.10 successfully compiles it inferring `Integer` type (replacing `+` by `/` changes the inferred type to `Double`). What is the explanation for that?

Comment: I know the answer in the linked question mentions defaulting, but still marking the question as a duplicate of "What is the monomorphism restriction?" is misleading since the monomorphism restriction is not relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell has a special case for dealing with the numeric classes (`Num`, `Fractional` and a few others) which picks a default type for ambiguous type variables. (See the [2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) for more details.)

The way it works is by trying a series of numeric types until one satisfies all of the constraints. By default it first tries `Integer` and then `Double`, but you can also control this on a per-module basis:

```
default (Int, Rational)
```

If you want to turn defaulting off for your module, just don't give it any types:

```
default ()
```

Honestly, this is a big hack to make Haskell easier to use as a calculator. But it does make life quite a bit easier since we don't have to explicitly annotate the types of literals in programs like yours, which would also be confusing.